# Moving mysql data from one database to another (slightly different) database

Tags: mysql

I took an open source product (applicant tracking system) and forked the code, and had some extra features added, which amounted to some extra tables in the MySQL database.

Now, I would like to load my data back into the mainstream product. How would I do that?

Compare the databases somehow, and delete the extra tables then run some command to restore? Does anyone have a high level suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I took an open source product ... and forked the code, and ... added ... some extra tables in the MySQL database ... I would like to load my data back into the mainstream product. How would I do that?

If I understand you correctly, you took a project and modified the database locally as you worked with it. Now you want to take your changes and apply them to what's, presumably, a running instance in production that doesn't have the changes yet.

Very briefly, since there's not that much info, you'll need to do the following:

- schedule some downtime for the current production instance;
- make the changes to the production database (i.e. run the SQL queries);
- apply the code changes that make use of the updated database;
- add/move any table data as necessary, *if* needed/applicable;
- verify that things are working correctly;

If what you're trying to do is get your changes into the upstream project itself (i.e. have your code merged into *their* codebase, etc), then you'll have to consult with the contribution guidelines for that particular project.

Comment: Both instances are off line. 
I was asking if there is an automated way to compare two MySQL database schema, and pare down one, to comply with the other... as I try to retrofit my forked application's database to the mainstream.

Comment: @zoomiest Then your original question wasn't clear. I'm not aware of a way to compare the actual databases (i.e. the binary files, etc). However, if you have the files with the SQL statements defining both schemas *and* you have them under version control, then you could use `git diff` to see the differences.